# ゲームアプリでステージごとにスコアを保存したい

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

#### 前提・実現したいこと

ゲームアプリを作っているのですが、ステージごとにスコアを保存したいです。
以下のように色々選択肢があるようなのですが、できればNSUserDefaultsを使いたいです。
・NSUserDefaults
・CoreData
・Parse

#### 考えてみたこと

以下のように配列の要素番号（`someArray[0]`）を各ステージにあわせて保存しようかと考えました。
ただもっと良い方法がありそうです。
アドバイスいただけるとありがたいです。

#### ソースコード

```
var someArray: [Int]!
var score = 0
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

//ステージの数だけ配列の要素を代入
someArray = [0,0,0,0,0]
someArray[0] = score
userDefaults.setObject(someArray, forKey: "someArray")    
userDefaults.synchronize()
someArray = userDefaults.objectForKey("someArray") as! [Int]
```

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/26357

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults に入れるのをint配列ではなくて、NSDictionary配列 にするとステージごとにほかのパラメーターも保存できるので便利になるかなと思います。

```
someArray = [
        ["score":0,"time":100],
        ["score":0,"time":100],
    ]
someArray[0]["score"] = score
userDefaults.setObject(someArray, forKey: "someArray")    
userDefaults.synchronize()
someArray = userDefaults.objectForKey("someArray") as! Array
```

CoreData,SQLite とか使うとソートが簡単にできるのでランキングがつくれますね。（初期設定に時間かかりそうですが...）
Parse だとインターネットランキングがつくれそうです。(Parseは終了するそうなので今から新しく作るならFirebaseでしょうか)